# What's the little square ahead of the project name in intellij idea, with a number in

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using idea as my java ide. I don't know which keys I have pressed, There appeared a little square ahead of the project name.
Is there anyone help tell what's this and what impact it has.

[image: little square]

Comment: Strange, it looks like a Numbered Mnemonic Bookmark, but I’ve no idea why that would be shown on a folder.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html

Comment: @racraman If you have `darcula` theme - it doesn't show up. If you switch to `light` theme, it shows up - then if you switch to darcula again - this time it stays.

Comment: @ersoy Ah, I am using Dracula theme - thanks for that .

Answer (score 2):

You bookmarked the folder and you may view it in `favorites`. After you open favorites, you may delete it by clicking the (-) on the bottom left corner.

> Also there is a bug i think. If it still shows-up after you remove from the bookmarks - switch theme to another one and go back to original one again. It disappears.

[image]